# Excel not picking up the XML element

Tags: xml, xsd, excel-2007

I have the following XML

```
  <flow>
      <material><mattext fontface="Arial"><p style="white-space: pre-wrap"><font size="11">This is my text content</font></p></mattext>
</material>
    </flow>
```

When I open it in Excel it picks up

```
fontface="Arial"
style="white-space: pre-wrap"
font size="11"
```

As attributes which I can generate a spreadsheet from

But is dosnt pick up "This is my text content" - which is the important bit

Can I generate some XSD file to deal with this or better yet get excel to render the html code as formatting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Excel 2007 (you use this according to the tag), when you open a XML file, it pops up a dialog box asking what to do with the xml file. There's three options.
First option is "As an XML table". Choose it.
It will say something about schema, just press OK.

It picked up the said content for me. It had four columns which contained,

| Arial  |  white-space: pre-wrap  |  This is my text content  |   11 |

This should solve your problem. If not, please elaborate the question.

Comment: how very strange - the above is a trimmed down code when i load the smaller version (above ) it works but when i load the bigger version full code it skips that text field

Comment: I see. Then, it's probably an issue with the xml <tags> that wraps the above content. First of all, have you done a xml validation for your document? There can be misplaced tags.